# Which Parent Form Event is Triggered When Subform is Entered?

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a main/parent form with multiple subforms and the main form fields are locked until the user clicks an "Edit" button.  This triggers an event which unlocks the fields.

When the user selects one of the subforms, I'd like to lock the fields again, but cannot find which main form event is triggered when activating the subform.  It doesn't appear to be LostFocus or Deactivate.

Which event on the parent form is triggered when one of its subforms is activated/entered?

Comment: Look at Forms!frmMyParentForm!frmMySubform.GotFocus

Comment: Johnny, I can add a line of code to each subform, but is there a ParentForm event triggered when moving to a subform?

Comment: It'd be tricky, but I think you could look at the OnClick event of the form, scroll through the controls to see which one got the focus, and if the ControlType=subform then you know to fire your code.  That's theoretical though, which is why I put it as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Take a look at this page to see which events get fired at what point, it might help you determine the best point to capture your click event: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Order-of-events-for-database-objects-E76FBBFE-6180-4A52-8787-CE86553682F9#bm3

Answer (score 1):

It is the *OnEnter* and *OnExit* events of the *subform control* on the parent form.